# Quando fechar um pool do postgres no NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express.js

Estou com uma aplicação NodeJS que basicamente tem um mecanismo de busca de alimentos. Entretanto sempre na segunda pesquisa ocorre a seguinte exceção e eu não sei em que parte do código exatamente eu devo abrir e fechar uma conexão com o banco.

```
(node:22204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot use a pool after calling end on the pool
```

Assim está meu código:

```
 try{
    let pool = require ('./conexao'); 
    let res = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM pesquisaAlimentos('?')", [str]);
    await pool.end();   
    return res.rows;
 }   catch(err){
    throw(err);
 }
```

O app.js está assim:

```
try {
        pesqAlimentos(pesq.barraPesq).then(result => {
            jsonRes = { "Alimentos" : result };
            res.status(200).json(jsonRes);
        });
    }   catch(err){
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
```

A minha maior dúvida é se eu devo usar o método pool.end() e quando devo, estou aprendendo NodeJS agora para um projeto da faculdade então não entendo muito bem seu funcionamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a propria documentacao do [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling),o `pool.end()` drena o pool de todos os clientes ativos, desconecta-os e encerra qualquer temporizador interno no pool. Isso é usado em aplicativos da web quando o servidor da web é encerrado intencionalmente ou por alguma tratativa de erro. 
Você pode usar `pool.end()` para fechar todos os clientes restantes, se tiver terminado com o pool. O objetivo do pool durante sua vida útil é manter os clientes vivos. 
Para desligar um 'pool', chame `pool.end ()`. Isso aguardará a devolucao de todos os clientes com check-out e desligará todos os clientes e os temporizadores do pool.
O pool retornará erros ao tentar fazer check-out de um cliente após você chamar `pool.end ()`, onde isso explica o erro que ocorre no seu codigo. 
Tente reescrever o seu codigo para algo parecido ao demonstrado na documentacao.

```js
    try{
     let pool = require ('./conexao');
 
     pool.query("SELECT * FROM pesquisaAlimentos('?')", (error, response) => {   
       console.log('Query terminada!');
       await pool.end();
       console.log('pool encerrada!'); 
   
       return res.rows;
     });
    }catch(err){
      throw(err);
    }
```